# Can I call a webhook from IBM Watsons conversational interface like API.ai

Tags: chatbot, watson-conversation, dialogflow-es

I'm familiar with using API.ai in a situation where an intent triggers an action which triggers a webhook that reaches out to an endpoint, then returns some info to API and then he client.

I'm wondering if the same is possible through Ibm Watson ( the GUI ), can't seem to find an example of the same scenario ... also, if this is possible, are there time restrictions ? For instance, in API, you must return from the request in 5 seconds .

Comment: Not sure you are looking for this one, but here is a toolkit that allows to pre- and post-process the Conversation calls: https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/botkit-middleware

Comment: @user379468 did you found anything? I'm also looking at the same problem

Answer (score 0):

You will have to handle it in application code by passing the context to the code.